# Problems implementing Lazy Load within Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, lazy-loading

I am trying to implement a lazy load wordpress plugin to a site for a client, the plugin is "[BJ Lazy Load](http://wordpress.org/plugins/bj-lazy-load/)" and the theme the client is using is "[Viewfinder](http://www.themezilla.com/themes/viewfinder/)".

The home page has 2400 120x120 thumbnail images which are all posts and the thumbnail images are attachments of the posts, with the full size image (that loads on click) being the posts featured image (see the image on viewfinder page for example.)

I installed the plugin but by default this only lazy loads images within the posts content which these are not. In the "other notes" the developer says to pass the following through a filter to use lazy load on all images:

```
    <?php
$img_html = '<img src="myimage.jpg" alt="">';
$img_html = apply_filters( 'bj_lazy_load_html', $img_html );
echo $img_html;
?>
```

I asked on the support forum as another user was having issues and I ended up using his code, pasting this in to functions.php file:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_status' => null,
'post_parent' => $fr_ID,
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
'order' => 'ASC'
);

$attachments = get_posts( $args );

if( $attachments ) {

$thumb_images = array();

foreach( $attachments as $key => $attachment ) { 

    $thumb_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment -> ID, 'thumbnail' );

    $thumb_images[] = $thumb_image[0];
}
natsort( $thumb_images );
}

// Apply lazy load filter to images
$img_lazy_load = '<img src="'.$thumb_images[0].'" alt="'.esc_attr( get_the_title() ).'" />';
$img_lazy_load = apply_filters( 'bj_lazy_load_html', $img_lazy_load );
echo $img_lazy_load;
```

No matter what I try, I cant seem to get this lazy load to work. Does anyone have any suggestions, other methods or alternative plugins I could try?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by installing and configuring the Plugin on a clean installation of WordPress first. If you can't get it functioning there after following the authors instructions you would probably benefit most from contacting the Plugin author and informing them as it would indicate there is a bug with the Plugin.

Comment: The plugin by default doesnt include images not in the post content, his extra filter makes this possible, it didnt work for me but I did speak to the developer who said he's not the best person to ask and to post on wordpress support forum.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings can you select that it works in the header as opposed to wp_footer, that's what worked for me. You can also try a plugin called Lazy Load (without the Bj).